# sql aggregate data

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

this is not a specific dbms question, but a generic sql problem.

i have this dataset

```
userid | objecteid| count
--------------------------
1      | 1        | 12
1      | 2        | 15
1      | 3        | 6
2      | 4        | 30
2      | 1        | 1
2      | 5        | 9
```

with one query i need to find: for each user, the object with the maximum count

looking for a result like this:

```
userid | objecteid| count
--------------------------
1      | 2        | 15
2      | 4        | 30
```

because the object 2 has the max count for user 1 and the object 4 has the max count for user 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be solved using window functions.

The following is standard ANSI SQL:

```
select userid, objecteid, "count"
from (
  select userid, objecteid, "count", 
         max("count") over (partition by userid) as max_cnt
  from the_table
) t
where "count" = max_cnt;
```

If there are two objects with the same `count`, both will be returned.

Alternatively this can also be done using `row_number()` instead:

```
select userid, objecteid, "count"
from (
  select userid, objecteid, "count", 
         row_number() over (partition by userid order by "count" desc) as rn
  from the_table
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Unlike the first query, this will only pick *one* row if a user has more than one object with the same count. If you want those duplicates returned, use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f02a9/1

Comment: missing objectid in the outer query

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Select * from tableName 
         where count in (
            Select Max(count) 
            from tableName 
            group by userid 
         )
```